# Thread vs Parallel.For performance

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I am struggling to understand the difference between **threads** and **Parallel.For**. I created two functions, one used Parallel.For other invoked threads. Invoking **10 threads** would appear to be **faster**, can anyone please explain? Would **threads** use **multiple processors** available in the system  (to get executed in parallel) or does it just do **time slicing** in reference to CLR?

```
public static bool ParallelProcess()
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

    sw.Start();
    Parallel.For(0, 10, x =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Printing {0} thread = {1}", x,
            Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
    });
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Time in secs {0}", sw.Elapsed.Seconds));

    return true;
}

public static bool ParallelThread()
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

    sw.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Thread1));
        t.Start();
        if (i == 9)
            t.Join();
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Time in secs {0}", sw.Elapsed.Seconds));

    return true;
}

private static void Thread1()
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Printing {0} thread = {1}", 0,
           Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
}
```

When called below methods, Parallel.For took twice time then threads.

```
Algo.ParallelThread(); //took 3 secs
Algo.ParallelProcess();  //took 6 secs
```

Comment: Your `ParallelThread` only wait for last thread to complete, but not all of them. Also, your threads do not consume CPU, because them are sleeping. `Parallel.For` is not optimized for such workload. It better suits for CPU intensive work.

Comment: Even though the Thread class is still useful and still has its uses, i would get to know your local tpl library, thread pools, tasks,. async await , and all the modern threading architecture and dont bother with Thread until you know you need it

Comment: Your tests are faulty.

Comment: Try a simple experiment, where you need to create 1 K  or 10 K threads, since that many elements needs parallel processing, you would know why using thread is bad idea and why TPL rocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a bunch of things here that are going wrong.

(1) Don't use `sw.Elapsed.Seconds` this value is an `int` and (obviously) truncates the fractional part of the time. Worse though, if you have a process that takes 61 seconds to complete this will report `1` as it's like the second hand on a clock. You should instead use `sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds` which reports as a `double` and it shows the total number of seconds regardless how many minutes or hours, etc.

(2) `Parallel.For` uses the thread-pool. This significantly reduces (or even eliminates) the overhead for creating threads. Each time you call `new Thread(() => ...)` you are allocating over 1MB of RAM and chewing up valuable resources before any processing can take place.

(3) You're artificially loading up the threads with `Thread.Sleep(3000);` and this means you are overshadowing the actual time it takes to create threads with a massive sleep.

(4) `Parallel.For` is, by default, limited by the number of cores on your CPU. So when you run 10 threads the work is being cut in to two steps - meaning that the `Thread.Sleep(3000);` is being run twice in series, hence the 6 seconds that it's running. The `new Thread` approach is running all of the threads in one go meaning that it takes just over 3 seconds, but again, the `Thread.Sleep(3000);` is swamping the thread start up time.

(5) You're also dealing with a CLR JIT issue. The first time you run your code the start-up costs are enormous. Let's change the code to remove the sleeps and to properly join the threads:

```
public static bool ParallelProcess()
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

    sw.Start();
    Parallel.For(0, 10, x =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Printing {0} thread = {1}", x, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
    });
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Time in secs {0}", sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds));

    return true;
}

public static bool ParallelThread()
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

    sw.Start();
    var threads = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(x => new Thread(new ThreadStart(Thread1))).ToList();
    foreach (var thread in threads) thread.Start();
    foreach (var thread in threads) thread.Join();
    sw.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Time in secs {0}", sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds));

    return true;
}

private static void Thread1()
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Printing {0} thread = {1}", 0, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));  
}
```

Now, to get rid of the CLR/JIT start up time, let's run the code like this:

```
ParallelProcess();
ParallelThread();
ParallelProcess();
ParallelThread();
ParallelProcess();
ParallelThread();
```

The times we get are like this:

```
Time in secs 3.8617
Time in secs 4.7719
Time in secs 0.3633
Time in secs 1.6332
Time in secs 0.3551
Time in secs 1.6148
```

The starting run times are terrible compared to the second and third runs that are far more consistent.

The result is that running `Parallel.For` is 4 to 5 times faster than calling `new Thread`.

Comment: Thanks for the detail response. Much appreciated. So, Thread.Sleep(3000) is causing new threads to be created after 3 secs, is it so? Also, Parallel.For was creating 3, 4 threads each time as default and was that the reason it took twice the time?

Comment: @FIrePanda - `Thread.Sleep(3000)` is **NOT** causing threads to be created after 3 seconds. There's nothing in your code that does that. `Parallel.For` doesn't necessarily create threads - if the thread-pool has them available it'll just use existing ones. It took twice the time because it was only executing on as many threads as there were cores available.

Answer (score 3):

`Parallel` utilizes however many threads the underlying scheduler provides, which would be the *minimum* number of threadpool threads to start with.

The number of *minimum* threadpool threads is by default set to the number of processors. As time goes on and based on many different factors, e.g. all current threads being busy, the scheduler might decide to spawn *more* threads and go higher than the minimum count.

All of that is managed for you to stop unnecessary resource usage. Your second example circumvents all that by spawning threads manually. If you explicitly set the number of threadpool threads e.g. `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 100)`, you'll see even the Parallel one takes 3 seconds as it immediately has more threads available to use.

Comment: Yes, you are right, setting ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 100) did improve performance. However, Setting ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(1, 1) won't increase the time, why?

Comment: @FIrePanda that's why I said it's the minimum _to start with_. Even if you lower the minimum, the threadpool might still have more threads available and will gradually retire them once not needed anymore. If you really want to hamper it immediately, you need to set the _maximum_ as well: `ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(1, 1)`

Comment: BTW, all of this is really just to explain what's happening. I don't recommend messing around with these values at all. If you really think you can manage the threads better, write a custom TaskScheduler that satisfies your circumstances and feed that into your Parallel.

Answer (score 1):

Your snippets are not equivalent. Here is a version of `ParallelThread` that would do the same as `ParallelProcess` but starting new threads:

```
public static bool ParallelThread()
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

    sw.Start();
    var threads = new Thread[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        int x = i;
        threads[i] = new Thread(() => Thread1(x));
        threads[i].Start();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        threads[i].Join();
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Time in secs {0}", sw.Elapsed.Seconds));

    return true;
}

private static void Thread1(int x)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Printing {0} thread = {1}", x,
           Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
}
```

*Here, I am making sure to wait for all the threads. And also, I making sure to match the console output. Things that OP code does not do.*

However, the time difference is still there.

Let me tell you what makes the difference, at least in my tests: the order. Run `ParallelProcess` before `ParallelThread` and they should both take 3 seconds to complete (ignoring the initial runs, which will take longer because of compilation). I cannot really explain it.

We could modify the above code futher to use the `ThreadPool`, and that did also result in `ParallelProcess` completing in 3 seconds (even though I did not modify that version). This is the version of `ParallelThread` with `ThreadPool` I came up with:

```
public static bool ParallelThread()
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

    sw.Start();
    var events = new ManualResetEvent[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        int x = i;
        events[x] = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem
            (
                _ =>
                {
                    Thread1(x);
                    events[x].Set();
                }
            );
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        events[i].WaitOne();
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Time in secs {0}", sw.Elapsed.Seconds));

    return true;
}

private static void Thread1(int x)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Printing {0} thread = {1}", x,
           Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
}
```

**Note**: We could use `WaitAll` on the events, but that would fail on a `STAThread`.

---

You have `Thread.Sleep(3000)` which are the 3 seconds we see. Meaning that we are not really measuring the overhead of any of these methods.

So, I decided I want to study this futher, and to do it, I went up one order of magnitud (from 10 to 100) and removed the `Console.WriteLine` (which is introducing synchronization anyway).

This is my code listing:

```
void Main()
{
    ParallelThread();
    ParallelProcess();
}

public static bool ParallelProcess()
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

    sw.Start();
    Parallel.For(0, 100, x =>
    {
        /*Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Printing {0} thread = {1}", x,
            Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));*/
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
    });
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Time in secs {0}", sw.Elapsed.Seconds));

    return true;
}

public static bool ParallelThread()
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

    sw.Start();
    var events = new ManualResetEvent[100];
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        int x = i;
        events[x] = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem
            (
                _ =>
                {
                    Thread1(x);
                    events[x].Set();
                }
            );
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        events[i].WaitOne();
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Time in secs {0}", sw.Elapsed.Seconds));

    return true;
}

private static void Thread1(int x)
{
    /*Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Printing {0} thread = {1}", x,
           Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));*/
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
}
```

I am getting 6 seconds for `ParallelThread` and 9 seconds for `ParallelProcess`. This remains true even after reversing the order. Which makes me much more confident that this is a real measure of the overhead.

Adding `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 100);` bring the time back down to 3 seconds, for both `ParallelThread` (remember that this version is using the `ThreadPool`) and `ParallelProcess`. Meaning that this overhead comes from the thread pool. Now, I can go back to the version that spawns new threads (modified to spawn 100 and with `Console.WriteLine` commented):

```
public static bool ParallelThread()
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

    sw.Start();
    var threads = new Thread[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        int x = i;
        threads[i] = new Thread(() => Thread1(x));
        threads[i].Start();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        threads[i].Join();
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Time in secs {0}", sw.Elapsed.Seconds));

    return true;
}

private static void Thread1(int x)
{
    /*Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Printing {0} thread = {1}", x,
           Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));*/
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
}
```

I get consistent 3 seconds from this version (meaning the time overhead is negligible, since, as I said earlier, `Thread.Sleep(3000)` is 3 seconds), however I want to note that it would be leaving more garbage to collect than using the `ThreadPool` or `Parallel.For`. On the other hand, using `Parallel.For` remains tied to the `ThreadPool`. By the way, if you want to degrade its performance, reducing the minimun number of threads is not enough, you got to degreade the maximun number of threads too (e.g. `ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(1, 1);`).

All in all, please notice that `Parallel.For` is easier to use, and harder to wrong.

---

> Invoking 10 threads would appear to be faster, can anyone please explain?

Spawning threads is fast. Although, it will leade to more garbage. Also, note that your test is not great.

> Would threads use multiple processors available in the system (to get executed in parallel) or does it just do time slicing in reference to CLR?

Yes, they would. They map to the underlaying operating system threads, can be preempted by it, and will run in any core according to their affinity (see `ProcessThread.ProcessorAffinity`). To be clear, they are not [fibers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_(computer_science)) nor coroutines.

Answer (score 0):

To put it in the simplest of the simplest terms, using `Thread` class guarantees to create a thread on the operating system level but using the `Parallel.For` the CLR thinks twice before spawning the OS-level threads. If it feels that it is a good time to create thread on OS-level, it goes ahead, otherwise it employs the available Thread pool. TPL is written to be optimized with a multi-core environment.

Comment: I wonder why the downvote! Was it because I had mistakenly skipped ThreadPool in the original answer?